# Testing the improper integral for convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Problem**

$\int_{0+}^{1-} \frac{\log(x)}{1-x}$

Test the convergence for this.

**My attempt**
Expansion of $\log(x)$ about 1, it can be easily seen that the integral converges since there is no singularities .

Is this attempt right?

Comment: Right but incomplete. What happens at $x=0$?

Comment: We can break the interval to avoid this i suppose .

Comment: Yes, you can and you should.

Comment: @blueboy Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\log x}{1-x}=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\log (1-y)}{y}=-1$$

and for $x \to 0^+$

$$\frac{\log x}{1-x}\sim \log x$$

and

$$\int \log x dx=x(\log x-1)+c$$

or, as an alternative,  since

$$\frac{\log x}{\frac1{\sqrt x}}=\sqrt x \log x \to 0$$

the given integral converges by limit comparison test with $\int \frac1{\sqrt x} dx$.